# How to rescue smoothie stains on the wall?

Tags: walls, painting, stain

I accidentally spilled quite some smoothie on the wall. It turns out to be very difficult to be cleaned. Now I am thinking about repainting the wall. The only issue is, we have a high ceiling room. It's about 3m-3.5m high. Repainting it sounds like a big pain. Does anyone have any suggestions? 
[image]

Comment: I've tried clean water (on the day it was spilled) and sparkling water so far. Neither helps.

Comment: That looks like one heck of a party! You might also try some cleaners like Formula409 or Oxyclean. If the walls are done in flat paint, you may not ever get them clean. Good luck :D

Comment: 3.5m isn't bad when you have an extension pole on your roller sleeve. And if you had a similar paint colour, you wouldn't necessarily have to cut in above ~2m.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to get a ladder, assuming you don't have one tall enough.  You could decorate the rest of the wall with more smoothie but painting would probably be the best bet. :)  If you do paint, test on some lower stains first and give them at least a day to see if the stains bleed through the paint.  It would be safer to just use some Kilz primer to seal the stain spots before repainting the wall.

Answer (score 1):

The splodges look like jellyfish. Add some fish and bubbles and tell people you redecorated.